# How to install/add personal certificate format (.pfx) to centos 7

Tags: installation, centos7, client-certificates

I have client_cert.pfx file, it's very easy install on windows (step by step).
But i don't know how can i do that on centos 7.

I need use client_cert because the website need authorize before response content.

I have research on internet, i can convert from (.pfx) to (.crt) and (.key) but i don't know where is locate for install them.

Can you please give me if you have idea or solution.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Linux doesn't have certificate stores the same way Windows does, so the answer is going to depend on why you want to do this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I want import client_certificate for server centos, because i will use CURL for get content website.